# JMXQuery connection - authentication failed

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, mbeans, nagios

Hey all. Newbie question time. I'm trying to setup JMXQuery to connect to my MBean, so far this is what I got.

java -classpath jmxquery org.nagios.JMXQuery -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8004/jmxrmi -O java.lang:type=Memory -A "NonHeapMemoryUsage"

Here's what I get.

JMX CRITICAL Authentication failed! Credentials required

I got the credentials, but how do I pass them to JMXQuery?

/Ace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source, you should be able to use -username  and -password  arguments.

http://code.google.com/p/jmxquery/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/jmxquery/JMXQuery.java?r=3

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an addon to the original JMX-query, look at the comment field.

> /**  *   * JMXQuery is used for local
>   or remote request of JMX attributes  *
>   It requires JRE 1.5 to be used for
>   compilation and execution.  * Look
>   method main for description how it can
>   be invoked.  *   * This plugin was
>   found on nagiosexchange.  It lacked a
>   username/password/role system.  *   *
>   @author unknown  * @author Ryan
>   Gravener (ryangravener@gmail.com)  *
>   */

Does that mean that there's no way to remotely access JMX with original JMXQuery? If so, what *can* you do with it?

Answer (score 0):

java -classpath jmxquery org.nagios.JMXQuery -U service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8004/jmxrmi -O java.lang:type=Memory -A NonHeapMemoryUsage -K used -I NonHeapMemoryUsage -J used -vvvv -w 82208358 -c 105696461 -username monitorRole -password changeme

Answer (score 0):

You can download a version of check_jmx that works with --username and --password from http://snippets.syabru.ch/nagios-jmx-plugin/download.html